# UnresolvedError on importing package in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I get an **`Unresolved Error`** while importing a package ([bigfloat](http://packages.python.org/bigfloat/)) by `import bigfloat` in PyDev in eclipse. However on `from bigfloat import *` the error is resolved. **What is the reason behind this?**

I used easy_install to download and install the `bigfloat` package. Does it not update the python_path in the process?? 
I have also tried adding the library as an external library in the pythonpath properties, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Is the error being reported by the PyDev / eclipse IDE, or does it happen when you run the code?

In the first case, this is probably due to eclipse caching the information about what packages you have installed.

What you need to do is go to "Preferences -> Pydev -> Interpreter - Python" where you define the python interpreter to be used. Remove the current interpreter, and add it back in again.

This will cause eclipse to re-read all the path information and it should clear the error.

Comment: Just to give more info, PyDev caches all information when the interpreter is configured. See: http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html and it may be that you may need to add something to the 'forced builtins' if the package cannot be statically analyzed properly (see 'forced builtins' in that same link).